# What's substitute for "Command-Accent (`)" shortcut on Mavericks?

Tags: osx-mavericks

According to [OS X keyboard shortcuts by Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343?viewlocale=en_US), there is a shortcut:

> Command-Accent (`) | Activate the next open window in the frontmost application

But it does not work on OSX Mavericks.

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut for the same function?

Comment: Works for me. If your keyboard language isn't US_en, it might be different for you though.

Comment: Thank you for your info. I also wanted to know other user's behavior. But I use English keyboard. Keyboard Input sources is U.S., and primary language is also English, but does not work. What do you mean by "keyboard language is US_en"?

Comment: It's actually en_US, and it's the standard keyboard layout you find on keyboards sold in the USA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of the OS/X operating system. You might find [apple.se] useful...


Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution. In my case,

> Command + F1

works.